# How to find the log file INSIDE a Docker container?

Tags: docker, logging

I know how to find the container log outside of a container; what I'm trying to figure out is if there's an easy way to find the path to the container's log file *inside* of the container?

i.e. let's say the log file inside the container is at: `/config/logs/blah.log`

Is there a way to quickly find that path if I (the prompt) were sitting at, say, `/home#`? (a command or something?)

Reason I ask is because it seems as if many container devs don't always put the log(s) in a standard place, and I often seem to have to go rooting through a bunch of directories trying to find it.

Comment: Assuming docker image is a Linux based image, you can use locate command to find all files. Before locate, update the index first using `updatedb` and then run `locate filename`

Comment: Thanks @kiner_shah, no luck though. I just tried it on a Linux based container & I get: `sh: updatedb: not found`, also `sh: locate: not found`. These are Alpine Linux based containers I believe.

Comment: Ohk, maybe you need to manually install those packages. Another alternative is to use `find` command like `find / -name "*filename*"`. BTW I haven't used Alpine Linux, so not sure why these commands aren't pre-installed in the image.

Comment: @kiner_shah Alpine is deliberately as minimalist as it can possibly be, in an effort to make containers as small as possible, so they leave out a ton of normally standard commands.

Comment: The container log (what's shown when you do `docker logs`) isn't inside the container, so there's no way to find it inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "find".

```
find /etc -type f -name "*.log"
```

would output all .log files found inside /etc. You can adjust this query as you need. See the [man page of find](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) for more details.

*Edit:* Just saw your comment about being on alpine.

Install find with `apk add findutils` if installing [useful additional components](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/How_to_get_regular_stuff_working) in your container is an option.